# Keyboard moving view up in react native expo

Tags: react-native

I am new in react native and I please need help. When the keyboard appears , the whole view is pushed upwards.I do not want that to happen.I saw other answers but none of them is working for me.I do not want the view to be pushed up when the keyboard appears and want to remain where they are.I am using expo and has given the code below with the images.

[image]

---

[image]

```
import { StatusBar } from 'expo-status-bar';
import React from 'react';
import { Image, StyleSheet, View, TextInput, Text, TouchableOpacity, ScrollView, KeyboardAvoidingView } from 'react-native';

export default function LoginScreen({ navigation }) {
  return (
        <View style={styles.container}>
          <Image style={styles.logo} source={
            {
              uri: "https://i.ibb.co/4JK4T3P/deale-logo.jpg",
            }} />
          <StatusBar style="auto" />
          <View style={styles.inputContainer} >
            <TextInput
              style={styles.loginInput}
              placeholder='Phone Number or Email'
            />
            <TextInput
              style={styles.passwordInput}
              placeholder='Password'
            />
            <TouchableOpacity
              style={{
                width: 280,
                height: 50,
                justifyContent: 'center',
                alignItems: 'center',
                backgroundColor: 'rgb(255, 77, 77)',
                elevation: 5,
                borderRadius: 10,
                top: 35
              }}
              activeOpacity={0.8}>
              <Text
                style={{
                  color: 'white',
                  fontSize: 15,
                  fontWeight: 'bold',
                }} >
                LOG IN
            </Text>
            </TouchableOpacity>
            <Text
              onPress={() => console.log('g')}
              style={{
                position: 'relative',
                top: '23%',
                fontWeight: 'bold',
              }} >
              OR LOGIN WITH SOCIAL MEDIA ACCOUNT?
          </Text>
            <View style={{
              flex: 1,
              flexDirection: 'row',
              bottom: 30,
              justifyContent: 'space-evenly',
              top: '22%',
              width: 300
            }} >
              <TouchableOpacity activeOpacity={0.5} >
                <Image source={
                  { uri: 'https://cdn3.iconfinder.com/data/icons/popular-services-brands/512/facebook-512.png' }}
                  style={{
                    width: 60,
                    height: 60,
                  }} />
              </TouchableOpacity>
              <TouchableOpacity activeOpacity={0.5} >
                <Image source={
                  { uri: 'https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/COxitqgJr1sJnIDe8-jiKhxDx1FrYbtRHKJ9z_hELisAlapwE9LUPh6fcXIfb5vwpbMl4xl9H9TRFPc5NOO8Sb3VSgIBrfRYvW6cUA' }}
                  style={{
                    width: 60,
                    height: 60,
                  }} />
              </TouchableOpacity>
            </View>
          </View >
          <View style={styles.loginButtonView} >
            <TouchableOpacity
              onPress={
                () => navigation.navigate('Create')
              }
              style={{
                width: '100%',
                height: '100%',
                justifyContent: 'center',
                alignItems: 'center',
                backgroundColor: 'rgb(145, 157, 230)',
                top: 10,
                elevation: 5,
                borderRadius: 5
              }}
              activeOpacity={0.8}>
              <Text
                style={{ color: 'white', fontSize: 15, fontWeight: 'bold' }} >
                CREATE ACCOUNT
            </Text>
            </TouchableOpacity>

            <TouchableOpacity
              style={{
                justifyContent: 'center',
                alignItems: 'center',
                top: '40%'
              }}
              activeOpacity={0.1}>
              <Text
                style={{
                  color: 'black',
                  fontSize: 16,
                  top: 5
                }} >
                FORGOT PASSWORD
            </Text>
            </TouchableOpacity>
          </View>
        </View >
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: '#fff',
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
  },
  logo: {
    position: 'absolute',
    height: 100,
    width: 150,
    resizeMode: "contain",
    top: '3 %'
  },
  loginInput: {
    position: 'relative',
    height: 50,
    borderColor: 'black',
    backgroundColor: 'rgb(240, 240, 242)',
    borderRadius: 10,
    width: 280,
    color: 'black',
    textAlign: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
    borderColor: 'white',
  },
  inputContainer: {
    position: 'absolute',
    top: '18%',
    alignItems: 'center',
  },
  passwordInput: {
    position: 'relative',
    height: 50,
    borderColor: 'black',
    backgroundColor: 'rgb(240, 240, 242)',
    borderRadius: 10,
    width: 280,
    color: 'black',
    textAlign: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
    borderColor: 'white',
    top: 10
  },
  loginButtonView: {
    position: 'absolute',
    height: 46,
    width: '70%',
    top: '80%'
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out the reason myself.It was happening because i had set my positions based on percentage and the popping of keyboard changed the dimensions resulting in the change of position.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use the component [KeyboardAvoidingView](https://reactnative.dev/docs/keyboardavoidingview) like this:

```
<KeyboardAvoidingView behavior={'height'} enabled style={styles.container}>
          <Image style={styles.logo} source={
            {
              uri: "https://i.ibb.co/4JK4T3P/deale-logo.jpg",
            }} />
          <StatusBar style="auto" />
          <View style={styles.inputContainer} >
            <TextInput
              style={styles.loginInput}
              placeholder='Phone Number or Email'
            />
            <TextInput
              style={styles.passwordInput}
              placeholder='Password'
            />
            <TouchableOpacity
              style={{
                width: 280,
                height: 50,
                justifyContent: 'center',
                alignItems: 'center',
                backgroundColor: 'rgb(255, 77, 77)',
                elevation: 5,
                borderRadius: 10,
                top: 35
              }}
              activeOpacity={0.8}>
              <Text
                style={{
                  color: 'white',
                  fontSize: 15,
                  fontWeight: 'bold',
                }} >
                LOG IN
            </Text>
            </TouchableOpacity>
            <Text
              onPress={() => console.log('g')}
              style={{
                position: 'relative',
                top: '23%',
                fontWeight: 'bold',
              }} >
              OR LOGIN WITH SOCIAL MEDIA ACCOUNT?
          </Text>
            <View style={{
              flex: 1,
              flexDirection: 'row',
              bottom: 30,
              justifyContent: 'space-evenly',
              top: '22%',
              width: 300
            }} >
              <TouchableOpacity activeOpacity={0.5} >
                <Image source={
                  { uri: 'https://cdn3.iconfinder.com/data/icons/popular-services-brands/512/facebook-512.png' }}
                  style={{
                    width: 60,
                    height: 60,
                  }} />
              </TouchableOpacity>
              <TouchableOpacity activeOpacity={0.5} >
                <Image source={
                  { uri: 'https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/COxitqgJr1sJnIDe8-jiKhxDx1FrYbtRHKJ9z_hELisAlapwE9LUPh6fcXIfb5vwpbMl4xl9H9TRFPc5NOO8Sb3VSgIBrfRYvW6cUA' }}
                  style={{
                    width: 60,
                    height: 60,
                  }} />
              </TouchableOpacity>
            </View>
          </View >
          <View style={styles.loginButtonView} >
            <TouchableOpacity
              onPress={
                () => navigation.navigate('Create')
              }
              style={{
                width: '100%',
                height: '100%',
                justifyContent: 'center',
                alignItems: 'center',
                backgroundColor: 'rgb(145, 157, 230)',
                top: 10,
                elevation: 5,
                borderRadius: 5
              }}
              activeOpacity={0.8}>
              <Text
                style={{ color: 'white', fontSize: 15, fontWeight: 'bold' }} >
                CREATE ACCOUNT
            </Text>
            </TouchableOpacity>

            <TouchableOpacity
              style={{
                justifyContent: 'center',
                alignItems: 'center',
                top: '40%'
              }}
              activeOpacity={0.1}>
              <Text
                style={{
                  color: 'black',
                  fontSize: 16,
                  top: 5
                }} >
                FORGOT PASSWORD
            </Text>
            </TouchableOpacity>
          </View>
        </KeyboardAvoidingView >
```

Try to use different values in the `position` prop.
If you want less job, you can use the [react-native-keyboard-aware-scroll-view](https://github.com/APSL/react-native-keyboard-aware-scroll-view). It's a very good lib to work with Keyboard in different layouts.

Comment: There is no prop called position and it is giving me error

Comment: Sorry, the correct name of the prop is [behavior](https://reactnative.dev/docs/keyboardavoidingview#behavior).